# How to get just the date number in SQL (E.g. if its 2013/06/22 I just need the 22)

Tags: mysql, sql

Does anyone know how to grab just the day number of the date result in SQL.

So for example if it was the 2013/06/22, what can I use to just grab the date number (22)?

Comment: so many programming languages, to answer this would take a while to guess which one you need.  just a simple reference to the language you need would get you an answer much quicker.. :)

Comment: Sorry I ment to include it was for SQL, How stupid

Comment: What kind of SQL?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

Comment: Thank You all, Yes I was using MYSQL, sorry for the hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MS SQL, you can use [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

```
SELECT DATEPART(dd, '2013/06/22');
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5178).

---

For MySQL, you can use [`DAYOFMONTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth):

```
SELECT DAYOFMONTH('2013-06-22');
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/15571).

---

Both return `22`.

Comment: Thank You, Yes I was using MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

In ANSI SQL standard, I don't believe there are any date time functions defined.

You should be clear on which DBMS you are asking.

In Oracle, you may do `to_char(aDate, 'dd')`

For example, `select to_char(sysdate, 'dd') from dual` give you day-of-month for current date.